# Power Query : replacing a cell's content by the previous one under conditions

Tags: replace, reference, powerquery

On a regular bases, I have to clean a CSV file.
I'd like to automate this task, what I'm trying to achieve with Power Query.

But I'm stuck on one process : in this file, some dates are wrongly filled (always with the same value - so that I can easily identify them), and I'd like to replace them with the previous row's one.
Is there a M language function allowing this kind of operations ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, Table.FillDown only fills on null values. Maybe first you can replace those wrong values with null, then you can call Table.FillDown on those columns?

Comment: Thanks Oğuz, but I feel the problem remains :  how do I get to the upper cell's content ?

Comment: When you call Table.FillDown on a column, Power Query will replace that cell's value with upper cell's value if the cell is null.

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you for using Power Query :)